# Python: Dynamic Slots Creation

Tags: python, python3

I am working on project where I need to create the logic for alternate slots in python. I tried on various different ways but I am unable to design exact logic to slots variable(series).

for example:
if nums_gpu = 1
, val = 2 * nums_gpu
, based on val -> slots = [0,0]

```
if nums_gpu = 2
, val = 2 * nums_gpu
, based on val -> slots = [0,1,0,1]

if nums_gpu = 3
, val = 2 * nums_gpu
, based on val -> slots = [0,1,2,0,1,2]
```

so on.

this might be very basic thing to ask but I tried a lot but couldn't create the exact logic. thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This site focuses on questions and answers related to Ubuntu. You may get better response if you ask this question in a python specific site. At the very least you should put the word "python" in the title so that those familiar with the language would take a look at your problem. Also edit your question and indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: @user68186 thank you, I created this question on stackoverflow and i am not sure why it's showing in askubuntu site.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create the logic.

```
nums_gpu = 5
slots = []
slots_bol = []
for x in range(nums_gpu):
    slots.append(x)
    slots_bol.append(True)

for x in range(nums_gpu):
    slots.append(x)
    slots_bol.append(True)
```